# How to plot min and max values on the barchart with LaTex?

Tags: plot, latex, bar-chart

Is there a way to plot the min and max values to the average bar-chart to be similar to the attached figure in below?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pgfplots` one can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [
        ybar,
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=both, y explicit,
    ] coordinates {
        (0,3) +- (0,1) 
        (1,2) +- (0,0.4) 
        (2,4) +- (0,1)
        (3,1) +- (0,0.6) 
        (4,2) +- (0,0.1)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what about if plotting from a table?

Comment: @HughPerkins If you have a new question, please use the "Ask question" button on the top right

Comment: well, the original question said nothing about the data not being from a table; so I feel my question is consistent with the original question in fact?

Comment: but sure, ok, will do

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596613/how-to-add-confidence-bars-around-a-graph-from-a-table